# How to Fix "No Activity found to handle Intent"

Tags: android, c++, qt, cryptocurrency

I have a portability QT application of DESKTOPs for the Android system.
In this application, I have a button that serves to open a certain folder where you have the backups of the program.
On Desktops works perfectly, however on the Android system I get errors.

Windows 64bits system, QT Creator 4.6.1, Crypto dependencies: boost_1_57_0, qrencode-4.0.2, openssl-1.0.2r, db-6.0.20, MiniUPnP, ifaddrs, and apache-ant-1.9.4

```
void showBackups()
{
    boost::filesystem::path pathBackups = GetDataDir() / "backups";

    /* Open folder with default browser */
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(pathBackups))
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QString::fromStdString(pathBackups.string())));
}
```

Source: https://github.com/DigitalCoin1/SperoCoin_Android

Implementation Commit:https://github.com/DigitalCoin1/SperoCoin_Android/commit/e8ad0468be0a5274d5841ecc1467d9c2557a3e29

```
W/System.err(10372): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///sdcard/Spero/backups typ=inode/directory }
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1861)
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1534)
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4125)
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4072)
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4396)
W/System.err(10372):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4364)
W/System.err(10372):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.openURL(QtNative.java:158)
W/System.err(10372):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative.startQtApplication(Native Method)
W/System.err(10372):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$6.run(QtNative.java:359)
W/System.err(10372):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run(QtThread.java:61)
W/System.err(10372):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Install an app that has an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` for that MIME type. There is no requirement for any Android user to have such an app. Note that you should crash on Android 7.0+ with a `FileUriExposedException` as well, given that `Intent` structure.

Comment: I installed ES FILE EXPLORER, but the error persisted.

Comment: Any reason for tagging `C` when this is clearly `C++`?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I edited and removed the tag.

Comment: "but the error persisted" -- I am not surprised, considering that `inode/directory` is not [an official MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: @CommonsWare would you have any solution?

Comment: I don't use Qt, and I can only guess from your code and the MIME type that you are trying to open an app to browse a directory. That concept doesn't really exist on Android. The simple solution is to just not call this on Android. Alternatively, you could build your own file browser, bearing in mind that it will be fairly obsolete in Android Q/R and beyond.

Comment: I understand ... Thank you very much for the help!